Is the centripetal acceleration of a particle greater at the lowest point or at the highest point?

As shown in the figure above, the center D of the blue circle revolves around the red circle once, and the particle G also revolves around the blue circle once. The path of particle G is the following three-dimensional curve:

The formula for the three-dimensional curve is as follows:
$curve(\frac{\sin(α+\tan⁻¹(R \sinα))}{\cos(\tan⁻¹(R \sinα))}, \frac{\cos(α+\tan⁻¹(R \sinα))}{\cos(\tan⁻¹(R \sinα))}, R \cosα, α, 0, 2π)$
The formula for the curve of this space is as follows:, R is the radius of the blue circle. The radius of the red circle is assumed to be $1$.
I know that the curvature of its highest point is small, while the curvature of its lowest point is large. But I don't know whether the centripetal acceleration at the highest point or the lowest point is greater when a particle moves along it.
The centripetal acceleration here refers to the acceleration pointing towards the center of curvature of a three-dimensional curve. The curvature at the highest and lowest points of this three-dimensional curve is different, and the center of curvature is also different.

Moving faster or slower or same speed? That matters!

Radius of curvature of a tangent circle at each point? That matters! Yes, it is small at the top, but how small?

@mmesser314  I have provided the formula for the curve, can the curvature of the highest and lowest points be calculated?

Yes it can. Radius of Curvature

@naturallyInconsistent   I supplemented my question.

@mmesser314  I supplemented my question.

You have not mentioned any speeds anywhere

@naturallyInconsistent  I only know that when a particle completes one circle along the blue circle, the center of the blue circle also completes one circle along the red circle. So I think the speed at the highest point is definitely greater than the speed at the lowest point. Can we assume that every second we make one circle along the blue circle and also one circle along the red circle? Does this mean we have speed? Because the angular velocity is the same.

The Blue circle is given with this equation
$$\mathbf P_k= \left[ \begin {array}{c} r\\ R\sin \left( \omega\,t
 \right) \\ R\cos \left( \omega\,t \right) 
\end {array} \right]
$$
rotate this circle about the z-axis you obtain the trajectory (red path)  of a mass point
$$\mathbf P_m= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \omega\,t \right) &-\sin
 \left( \omega\,t \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \omega\,t
 \right) &\cos \left( \omega\,t \right) &0\\  0&0&1
\end {array} \right] 
\,\mathbf P_k$$
from here the centrifugal acceleration is
$$a_c(t,\omega)=\frac{|\mathbf v|^2}{\rho}=
\frac{| \mathbf v\times \mathbf a|}{|\mathbf v|}\quad,
\rho=\frac{|\mathbf v|^3}{| \mathbf v\times \mathbf a|} $$
with
$$\mathbf v=\dot{P}_m\quad,\mathbf a=\ddot{P}_m
 $$
evaluate $~a_c~$ at the top (t=0), and at the bottom $~(t=\frac{\pi}{\omega}~)$ you obtain
$$ a_T^2= \left( 5\,{R}^{2}+4\,Rr+{r}^{2} \right) {\omega}^{4}\\
a_B^2= \left( 5\,{R}^{2}-4\,Rr+{r}^{2} \right) {\omega}^{4}\quad\Rightarrow\\
\frac{a_T^2}{a_B^2}={\frac {5\,{R}^{2}+4\,Rr+{r}^{2}}{5\,{R}^{2}-4\,Rr+{r}^{2}}}\quad\Rightarrow ,a_T > a_B$$
thus the centripetal acceleration at  the top is greater then the
centripetal acceleration at the bottom



I assume you mean the circles rotate at uniform speeds. The centripetal acceleration would be the same at top and bottom.
Suppose you had a second pair of rotating circles just like the first, but upside down. You would not be able to tell which was which. They would look the same and move the same.

What is your basis? What I mean is: the center of the blue circle rotates around the origin along the red circle, with a constant angular velocity. The particle moves along a blue circle and rotates around the center of the blue circle, with a constant angular velocity.
